# How can Yard document a Ruby method returning the type of the yield block?

Tags: ruby, yard

I have a method that optionally takes a block.

It either returns an array of the parameters it would have supplied to an absent block, or transparently returns the result of yield.

I know I can use `@overload` to treat the block/no-block causes differently, but how can I tell it that `@return` for the block clause is whatever the block handed me? If this were Kotlin, I'd use a type parameter with_build_parameters(...) or whatever.

```
# @overload with_build_parameters
#   @return [Array] if no block is given
# @overload with_build_parameters(&block)
#   @yieldparam [Hash<String, String>] config_props
#   @yieldparam [Hash<String, String>] build_props
#   @yieldreturn [T] whatever you like
#   @return [T] whatever the block said
```

I'm mainly interested in getting this to work with RubyMine's type checking.

Comment: did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @marknuzz No - we migrated to Kotlin away from Ruby.